# User and group setting on symfony2 framework

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have symfony system which write and read on file programs so,

I set every file's owner to apache with `chown -R apache:apache *`

However I need to deploy these files by user `whitebear` from capifony(deploy tool)

How should I set the the group or user???

I make a new group and add `apache` and `whitebear` to it , is it good way??

Or is there any standard practice for symfony | php project??

Comment: [The standard practice](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this step by step.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to change to capistrano 3 because capifony is unmaintained. Otherwise, you should add :

Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/file-permissions'
```

deploy.rb

```
set :file_permissions_roles, :all
set :file_permissions_chmod_mode, "0755"
set :file_permissions_paths, ["var/logs", "var/cache"]
set :file_permissions_users, ["apache"]
set :file_permissions_groups, ["whitebear"]
```

I hope this going to help you.